# Display certain types of ads in admob?

Tags: android, admob

New at using admob within Android.  Is it possible to show ads with certain keywords more frequently?  The opposite of text filters.

Example, my app is targeted for people interested in Japanese culture, language, etc..  Is it possible to display ads that are relevant with the keyword "Japanese".  I noticed I was able to search ads on admob.com using the keyword and a lot of valid ads came up.  I would like my app to display these relevant ads more so than the broad spectrum of ads it displays now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't. 
they are generated based on the users preferences.
if google sense that you're a girl looking for red sues, it will display ads containing red sues even if you say to admob to give you ads with "cars" keywords.